# Overriding Cached routes in Axios Cache Adapter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just added a very basic caching system for my app on GET requests via [axios-cache-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter) library.

Works great, but there are situations where I would like to get fresh data (especially after updating some value). How can I accomplish this while using this library?

The docs make no mention of cache busting.

Below is my setup.

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store'
import { setupCache } from 'axios-cache-adapter'

const cache = setupCache({
  maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000
})

const AxiosConfig = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL,
  adapter: cache.adapter
})

const addToken = (config) => {
  const token = store.getters['AuthModule/getAuthToken']
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  }
}

AxiosConfig.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    addToken(config)
    return config
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

export default AxiosConfig
```

Comment: I think making `maxAge` to 0 should do the trick in those cases. Meaning that the config would change on specific requests

Comment: You should look at the 'invalidate' option in package docs. You can customise it to invalidate after updating the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [invalidate the cache entry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter#invalidate-cache-entries) per request by setting up the `cache.invalidate` hook to remove the entry based on a flag (e.g., named "`clearCacheEntry` "):

```js
import { setup } from 'axios-cache-adapter'

const axiosInstance = setup({
  cache: {
    // Invalidate only when a specific option is passed through config
    invalidate: async (config, request) => {
      if (request.clearCacheEntry) {
        await config.store.removeItem(config.uuid)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then set the `clearCacheEntry` option when making the request:

```js
axiosInstance.get('https://httpbin.org/get', { clearCacheEntry: true })
  .then(response => {
    // Response should not come from cache
    assert.ok(response.request.fromCache !== true)
  })
```